# How to override log4j.properties during testing?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, maven-2, maven-surefire-plugin

I'm trying to log all `DEBUG` messages to console during testing in maven. For this purpose I created a file `src/test/resources/log4j.properties`, which is going to override the configuration I already have in `src/main/resources/log4j.properties`. Unfortunately such an overriding is not happening. Why and how to fix it?

Comment: @Bozho I also think so, but looks like these two files conflict. When I have them two NO logging config works. They both are just ignored...

Comment: I think maven just includes both resources in path, so log4j gets confused which one to use and instead just fails by not showing anything. Does Robert's solution work?

Comment: Bozho is right, it works fine as it is. The problem was with my logging configuration. I used `slf4j-jdk14` instead of `slf4j-log4j`. Everything works fine **without** the trick offered by Robert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work as it is, and it works. The problem is somewhere else.

ps. I had a mess with loggers in my classpath: jog4j, slf4j, logback (from other dependencies). As I understand, all of them are in conflict. I didn't clean this mess yet, and I still don't know how to make all packages to use one logging facility and one configuration.

Comment: How is that you didn't clean the mess. don't know how to make them all work together and get the correct answer?

Answer (score 28):

Rename your test configuration file to e.g. `log4j-surefire.properties` and configure log4j to pick it up during surefire execution:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <configuration>
        <systemPropertyVariables>
            <log4j.configuration>file:${project.build.testOutputDirectory}/log4j-surefire.properties</log4j.configuration>
        </systemPropertyVariables>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: I up-voted your answer, many thanks for it. Unfortunately, it is not helpful in my case, since the problem is not with the location of the file, but of `log4j` usage together with `slf4j`.

Answer (score 0):

Beware of changed version for that, with 2.17.1 of log4j at least, **you'll have to change it from** `log4j.configuration` **to** `log4j.configurationFile` to avoid having

`ERROR StatusLogger Reconfiguration failed: No configuration found for '18b4aac2' at 'null' in 'null'`

Here an example

```
        <plugin>
            <!--            DOC http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html -->
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.surefire.version}</version>
            <!-- enables java assertions for tests -->
            <configuration>
                <enableAssertions>true</enableAssertions>
                <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <log4j.configurationFile>src/test/resources/log4j2_for_surefire.xml</log4j.configurationFile>
                </systemPropertyVariables>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```