# log4j.properties in my /src/test/resources is not overriding main

Tags: maven, log4j

How do I get my `src/test/resources/log4j.properties` file to override my `/src/main/resources/log4j.properties` during testing?  The first ends up under `target/test-classes`, and the second is under `target/classes`.

Yes, I've looked for [duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106524/how-to-override-log4j-properties-during-testing), but in this case, I don't have a mix of loggers - I'm using 
only slf4j-log4j12.

Answer (score 0):

You could use maven profiles combined with filtering and maven-war-plugin, all in pom.xml. With this you can define what you need to have in log4j.properties.

Example with logback:

Defining a variable in config.test.properties:

```
basepath_log=/var/log/ProjectName
```

Defining a placeholder in logback.xml (equivalent to log4j.properties):

```
<appender>
...
    <file>${basepath_log}/ProjectName.log</file>
...
</appender>
```

Profile definition:

```
<profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>test</id>
            <properties>
                <targetenv>test</targetenv>
            </properties>
        </profile>
</profiles>
```

Filtering (pom.xml):

```
<filters>
    <filter>src/main/resources/filter/config.${targetenv}.properties</filter>
</filters>
```

Then you could use profiles directly with maven using option -Ptest or selecting it in your IDE (Netbeans, Eclipse...)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, my bad.  [This bug](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-3118) suggested maybe my issue was a dependency on a bad version.  Sure enough - 2.3 was too old; updated version behaves as expected.