# Override log4j config available in a dependency to run unit/integration tests

Tags: java, eclipse, log4j, maven-3, junit4

I have a multi module Maven project (following standard conventions) with the following structure:

- module "core" contains the reusable code
- modules "a", "b" & "c" all have "core" as their dependency apart from their own stuff. There are many modules like "a", "b" and "c" (more than 20).

There is a log4j.xml file in test/resources for modules "a", "b" and "c" but no log4j.xml in main/resources of these. The reason being that I want a different logging config for each module.

However, due to a recent change in requirements that requires the main application to send logs to email, I have added a log4j.xml with the SMTPAppender to main/resources of "core". 
I had hoped that this would make the log4j.xml available in the classpath of all three modules and the email would work. Also, I had hoped that the test/resources/log4j.xml in the individual modules "a", "b" and "c" would override that of "core" and would behave as before.

This didn't happen though. The main/resources/log4j.xml from "core" is available in the classpath even during tests, causing the test to try sending emails which I do not want.

So, I would like a solution that will ensure that the main/resources/log4j.xml from "core" will not be used when the tests run in "a", "b" and "c".

I searched for other similar posts and found this: [How to override log4j.properties during testing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106524/how-to-override-log4j-properties-during-testing) which is similar but different. It talks about overriding log4j.xml in the "same" project but my case is different since this is about overriding a log4j.xml available in a dependency. Also, I do not want to rename test/resources/log4j.xml to something else and configure surefire plugin to use that, due to two reasons:

- I have many modules like "a", "b" & "c" where I'd have to do that, which I don't want
- That would make the code look magical at first glance for other developers until they figure out (or I communicate in the docs) that there's a hidden trick in the pom.xml.

Does this have a simpler solution? All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you switched to log4j2 or logback you would solve this problem easily. These two look for log4j2-test.xml / logback-test.xml in the first place. So test configuration overrides main configuration.

Comment: Thanks for a great idea. However, at this point of time difficult to accomplish within my deadline as a dependency upgrade would require many nods. I have this noted anyway.

Answer (score -1):

In each applications "a","b","c" you can move "log4j.xml" from "main/resources" to deeper package, for example, for application "a": "main/resources/com/mycompany/a".
Path to required "log4j.xml" can be specified in concrete application in several ways:

1) With system properties, for ex.

```
export TOMCAT_OPTS="-Dlog4j.debug -Dlog4j.configuration=foo.xml"
```

2) With PropertyConfigurator during application start:

```
PropertyConfigurator.configure(AApplication.class.getClassLoader().getResource("com/mycompany/a/log4j.properties"));
```

3) In web application concrete "log4j.xml" can be specified in "web.xml".

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, please note that  "a","b","c" do not have log4j.xml in main/resources. They only have it in test/resources. The log4j.xml in main/resources is coming from a dependency. I am looking for a way that ideally, would not make me tweak the log4j.xml filename in every module ("a", "b", "c" etc.) or the module pom.xml in a way that would require detailed documentation of purpose of the tweak for the sake of future modules to follow suit.